# Issues with VSC and nRF Connect SDK Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, nrf52, nrf-connect

> Running:
> VSC - 1.69.1`
> nRF Connect SDK v2.0.0
> nRF Connect for Desktop v3.11.1
> nRF Toolchain Manager v1.1.3
> nRF Connect Extension for VSC v2022.7.207

The `nRF Connect` Extension of VSC did an update this morning, and now all my paths seem to be screwed up.

When I go into the Welcome Page for nRF Connect for VSC, to check where my paths are pointing to, I get this error:

[screen shot of welcome page showing nRF Connect Toolchain issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OMYE.png)

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling pretty much everything, but somewhere VSC seems to remember that I have all the various extensions installed, and that error keeps popping up.

Basically means it can't find west or any of the other build tools.  So my development has come to a grinding halt.

Got a colleague with exactly the same set up, and his is working fine, so its clearly something in the setup that I have no idea of that's screwing things up.

Bit of a novice with configuring dev environments at this level, so go easy on me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, updating "nRF Connect for VS Code" to v2022.7.242 solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue.

Unsuccessful download of the SDK is my cause. **I fixed them by switching my network(using mobile network)**.

Have you verified that all files have been downloaded completely?
Check the "C:ncsv2.0.0" folder, and look for the correct files as in the sample below.

[image]